# Join negative particle

Tags: python, join, nlp

How to attach a negative particle to the next word in python (for all texts where "no" can be)?

For example, make this string `['This is not apple']`

Into this: `['This is not_apple']`

Comment: your input is a list, not a string (you might want to update your question to clarify)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

`\bnot\s+(?=\w)` to match the word `not` (but not other words ending in `not`) followed by one or more space and another word.

```
import re

s = 'This is not apple'

s2 = re.sub(r'\bnot\s+(?=\w)', 'not_', s)
```

output: `'This is not_apple'`

###### with a list

```
import re

l = ['This is not apple']
[re.sub(r'\bnot\s+(?=\w)', 'not_', s) for s in l]
```

output: `['This is not_apple']`

Comment: Thank you, it works!  This is exactly what I had.